# In CodeIgniter, how to call ajax url from controller with parameters for pagination

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, codeigniter

I need to add pagination to my datatable. I don't know how to add ajax url. My controller name is task and my function is

**Controller task.php**

```
public function view($taskid,$page=0){

}
```

**View page JavaScript**

```
var table = $('#taskss-table').DataTable({
      "processing": false,
        "pagingType" : "full_numbers",
        "pageLength" : 15,
        "serverSide": true,
        "orderMulti": false,
        "order": [3,"asc"],
        "columns": [
          null,
          null,
          null,
        { "orderable": false }
      ],
       "ajax": {
            url : "<?php echo site_url("tasks/view/" .$taskid."/0") ?>",
            type : 'GET',
            data : function ( d ) {
                d.search_type = $('#search_type').val();
            }
        },
        "drawCallback": function(settings, json) {
        $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
      }
    });
```

My error is "unexpected token" in ajax url.

Comment: Can you show me whole error which are you getting in inspect element -> network tab ?

Answer (score 1):

```
url : "<?php echo site_url("tasks/view/" .$taskid."/0") ?>",
```

to

```
url : '<?php echo site_url("tasks/view/" .$taskid."/0") ?>',
```

Comment: Thanks AZinkey...I resolved that ..now the issue is the records are not fetching ..I am getting error {"draw":1,"recordsTotal":"0","recordsFiltered":"0","data":[]

Comment: is your view function received params ?

Comment: Yeah...But I cant figure out in which part error is arising?